# ModelForm Upload Multiple Images: not saving images in static folder

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

> I have been trying to code a Multi Upload for Images, my code only
>   uploads 1 image even though more than 1 is selected, I don´t know how to iterate through, I did a print once the files were selected and my multiple images selected are printed, but when I save the form it only saves one image.
>
> I basically trying to use the code that appear in the Django
>   documentation.

**models.py**

```
class Images(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/photoadmin/pictures')
```

**forms.py**

class UploadImages(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('picture',)
        widgets = {'picture': forms.ClearableFileInput(
            attrs={'multiple': True})}

**views.py**

```
 class Upload(FormView):
    form_class = UploadImages
    template_name = 'photoadmin/upload.html'
    success_url = 'photoadmin/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('picture')

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            for f in files:
                file_instance = Images(picture=f)
                file_instance.save()

                return render(request, 'photoadmin/index.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'photoadmin/index.html')
```

**html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

<p><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

> This code write in the DB but do not uploads the file to the static
>   folder

Comment: I think it should not be `form.save()`. You want to save every file instead.

Comment: Hi, I searched for another way to save but I can´t find anything different besided form.save(), can you suggest me another way?Thanks for your help

Comment: Please check my answer. I'm not sure if it will work or not because I have never dealed with class based forms.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to save every file individually, using `FileSystemStorage`

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
...

class Upload(FormView):
    form_class = UploadImages
    template_name = 'photoadmin/upload.html'
    success_url = 'photoadmin/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            files = request.FILES.getlist('picture')
            if form.is_valid():
                fs = FileSystemStorage()
                for file in files:
                    fs.save(file.name, file)
                return render(request, 'photoadmin/index.html')
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: Hi, I get the following error: Exception Value: 
name 'file' is not defined. I tried to define it but I'm new to all this and it didn´t work.

Comment: Hi, so I tried many ways and I still can achieve the multiupload for images, I got back and got rid of the Exception Value that I catch due to an error in my code, I don´t get the error anymore, but it does not upload any file with the solution you kindly provided, the example that I'm trying is in the Django Documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 0):

**So, this is finally the solution.**

**views.py**

```
class UploadView(generic.CreateView):
form_class = UploadImages
model = PostSession
template_name = 'photoadmin/upload.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('upload')

def form_valid(self, form):
    object = form.save(commit=False)
    form.save()
    if self.request.FILES:
        for afile in self.request.FILES.getlist('picture'):
            img = object.images.create(picture=afile)

    return super(UploadView, self).form_valid(form)
```

> with that you are able to iterate

**models.py**

```
class PostSession(models.Model):
session_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.session_name)


class Images(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(
        PostSession, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures')
```

> Hope this helps the community!